# Registry - search child values to change parent value

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, registry

I am looking to change a registry value based on a value found within its child key in [powershell-v4.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-v4.0). Please see the below diagram.

```
- scripts
  - {ID}
    + ScriptState = 0 #This is the value I am looking to change
    - properties
      + {ID},E = 'Activated' #based on the values of these registry values
      + {ID},V = 'Hard Drive' #based on the values of these registry values
```

Legend:

`+ = Value
 - = Key`

All of the IDs are randomly generated, and I am having trouble looping through/getting a list of the randomly generated key IDs. Once I am able to loop through those key IDs then the rest should be fairly easy.

Below is the current script I am using that attempts to locate and filter the child keys (changing parent's parent's key value not yet implemented).

`V1`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $key -rec | foreach { 
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.PSPath -rec  } | foreach {
    $CurrentKey = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PsPath) } |
    select-string "REGEX TO FIND VALUES" -input $CurrentKey -AllMatches | 
    foreach {($_.matches)| select-object Value
}
```

`V2`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $key -rec | foreach {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.PSPath -rec   | foreach {
    $CurrentKey = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PsPath)
    if ($CurrentKey -match "REGEX TO FIND VALUES") {
        $CurrentKey
    }
}}
```

Neither of the above scripts produces any results and I'm hoping that someone can explain why they are not giving any result or point me towards a code that will accomplish the objective stated above.

Comment: So, what is the question? :-)

Comment: Apologies, I left out the most important part. I have now updated the question with a question...

Answer (score 0):

Once you've done a Get-ChildItem -Recurse on the parent, you don't need to do an additional -Recurse on the ChildItem. All of the ChildItems are already in memory and ready to be used in your pipeline. I'm not sure if the below will help but this is how I'd go about finding a value somewhere in a list of keys.

```
$DebugPreference = 'Continue'
#Any Get-ChildItem with -Recurse will get all items underneath it, both childitems and their childitems.
$regKeySet = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall -Recurse
foreach($childKey in $regKeySet)
{
    Write-Debug -Message "Processing registry key $($childKey.Name)"
    #You can pick any property you want, the -ErrorAction is set here to SilentlyContinue to cover the instances 
    #where the specific childitem does not contain the property you are looking for, the errors are typically non-terminating but it cleans up the red.
    $publisherInfo = Get-ItemProperty $childKey.Name -Name Publisher -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if($publisherInfo.Publisher -ieq 'Microsoft Corporation')
    {
        #Do stuff here, you mention doing something to the parent, this is easily accomplished by 
        #just referecning the $childKey that is in this loop. If the publisher equals something you can then manipulate any property of the parent you would like.
        Write-Host "Found the publisher I wanted: $($publisherInfo.Publisher)." -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```